# What to consider to optimize the throughput for gsutil rsync/cp command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, transfer, throughput

I'm currently transferring 32 of 4GB files from Google Compute Engine instance to Google Cloud Storage. And I am currently trying to maximize my throughput during this process with "-m" and "-o [GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M, GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=32]". But I was wondering if there are any other things I should consider and take advantage of(especially with boto configuration) to boost the throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The default options are fine.

Increasing the buffer size beyond 512 KB has little impact on network performance. Increasing the number of threads beyond 4 has little impact as well.

The size of the Compute Engine instance and the distance between Compute Engine and Cloud Storage will have the most impact on performance.